# matlab k-means clustering evaluation

Tags: matlab, k-means

How effectively evaluate the performance of the standard matlab k-means implementation.

For example I have a matrix X

```
X = [1  2;
     3  4;
     2  5;
     83 76;
     97 89]
```

For every point I have a gold standard clustering. Let's assume that (83,76), (97,89) is the first cluster and (1,2), (3,4), (2,5) is the second cluster. Then we run matlab

```
idx = kmeans(X,2)
```

And get the following results

```
idx = [1; 1; 2; 2; 2]
```

According the the NOMINAL values it's very bad clustering because only (2,5) is correct, but we don't care about nominal values, we care only about points that is clustered together. Therefore somehow we have to identify that only (2,5) gets to the incorrect cluster.

For me a newbie in matlab is not a trivial task to evaluate the performance of clustering. I would appreciate if you can share with us your ideas about how to evaluate the performance.

Comment: I ran your code on MATLAB 2013a and got idx = [1; 1; 1; 2; 2], which looks fine.

Comment: I get the same result as @lanpa in MATLAB R2012b. Which version are you using?

Comment: Just for the sake of comparison, with R2014a I got [2;2;2;1;1].

Comment: The result is not the point of the question, the point is how to evaluate the performance of matlab k-means given gold standard clustering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate the "best clustering" is somewhat ambiguous, especially if you have points in two different groups that may eventually cross over with respect to their features.  When you get this case, how exactly do you define which cluster those points get merged to?  Here's an example from the [Fisher Iris dataset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) that you can get preloaded with MATLAB.  Let's specifically take the sepal width and sepal length, which is the third and fourth columns of the data matrix, and plot the `setosa` and `virginica` classes:

```
load fisheriris;
plot(meas(101:150,3), meas(101:150,4), 'b.', meas(51:100,3), meas(51:100,4), 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 24)
```

This is what we get:

[image]

You can see that towards the middle, there is some overlap.  You are lucky in that you knew what the clusters were before hand and so you can measure what the accuracy is, but if we were to get data such as the above and we **didn't know what labels each point belonged to**, how do you know which cluster the middle points belong to?

---

Instead, what you should do is try and minimize these classification errors by running `kmeans` more than once.  Specifically, you can override the behaviour of `kmeans` by doing the following:

```
idx = kmeans(X, 2, 'Replicates', num);
```

The `'Replicates'` flag tells `kmeans` to run for a total of `num` times.  After running `kmeans` `num` times, the output memberships are those which the algorithm deemed to be the best over all of those times `kmeans` ran.  I won't go into it, but they determine what the "best" average is out of all of the membership outputs and gives you those.

Not setting the `Replicates` flag obviously defaults to running one time.  As such, try increasing the total number of times `kmeans` runs so that you have a higher probability of getting a higher quality of cluster memberships.  By setting `num = 10`, this is what we get with your data:

```
X = [1  2;
     3  4;
     2  5;
     83 76;
     97 89];
num = 10;
idx = kmeans(X, 2, 'Replicates', num)

idx =

     2
     2
     2
     1
     1
```

You'll see that the first three points belong to one cluster while the last two points belong to another.  Even though the IDs are flipped, it doesn't matter as we want to be sure that there is a clear separation between the groups.

## Minor note with regards to random algorithms

If you take a look at the comments above, you'll notice that several people tried running the `kmeans` algorithm on your data and they received different clustering results.  The reason why is because when `kmeans` chooses the initial points for your cluster centres, these are chosen **in a random fashion**.  As such, depending on what state their random number generator was in, it is not guaranteed that the initial points chosen for one person will be the same as another person.

Therefore, if you want reproducible results, you should set the random seed of your random seed generator to be the same before running `kmeans`.  On that note, try using [`rng`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) with an integer that is known before hand, like `123`.  If we did this before the code above, everyone who runs the code will be able to reproduce the same results.

As such:

```
rng(123);
X = [1  2;
     3  4;
     2  5;
     83 76;
     97 89]; 
num = 10;
idx = kmeans(X, 2, 'Replicates', num)

idx = 

    1
    1
    1
    2
    2
```

Here the labels are reversed, but I guarantee that if any else runs the above code, they will get the same labelling as what was produced above each time.

Comment: "You are lucky in that you knew what the clusters were before hand and so you can measure what the accuracy is" this is exactly the points of the question, how to measure the accuracy given gold standard, as I show in my example, it is not trivial

Comment: @fog - That again is ambiguous.  The arrangements of the cluster IDs are random.  For example, the ideal output of `kmeans` would either be `[1 1 1 2 2]` or `[2 2 2 1 1]`.  We don't know how these IDs are going to be assigned, and so trying to calculate classification accuracy is not easy.... so I don't have an answer for you there!  In the end, I can recommend increasing the number of repetitions to decrease the probability of misclassification.  Good lucK!