# Finding accuracy after convergence is met

Tags: algorithm, k-means

I've completed coding a part for k-means clustering and its enhanced version.
My question is: after the clustering part, how do we find the accuracy?

I've googled for it but was of no use. I've taken a sample dataset as Irisdata with k as 3, clustering is done, any help on how to find the accuracy?

Comment: [This thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108125/clustering-accuracy) on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ may get you started. Your question doesn't seem quite right for SO and if the linked thread doesn't help, I suggest posting your question there.

Comment: Duplicate of [Evaluating K-means accuracy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800447/evaluating-k-means-accuracy) and [matlab k-means clustering evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844767/matlab-k-means-clustering-evaluation), amongst others both here and on Stats.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the **Adjusted Rand Index** which seems to be the most popular measure for comparing a clustering to a labeled ground truth.